# Rosbag in Roslaunch, save rosbag to specific directory

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosbag, launch-file

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey I wanted to use robsbag record in a roslaunch file like:

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record" output="screen"/>
```

How do I specify that I want to save the bag with a timestamp and to a specific location?

I am running on an embedded hardware and have therefore installed the needed ros packages for perception: ros-indigo-perception and ros-indigo-rosbag. Do I need any other packages?

I can run Rosbags without any issue, but start recording keeps failing. Running the following from the commandline, instead of launch file, achieves what I want:

```
rosbag record -o ~/../../media/ubuntu/E04E-7229/Rosbag/ -a
```

But running the command in the roslaunch file:

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record" output="screen" args="-o ~/../../media/ubuntu/E04E-7229/Rosbag/ -a" launch-prefix="xterm -e"/>
```

makes it crash with Error opening file! I tried changing the write rights for the launch file, but the error persists

> Error writing: Error opening file: ~/Desktop/_2016-10-13-07-27-39.bag.active

The error was apparently now does not exist when writing to the Desktop but only when I write to the SD-Card. Nevertheless the .bag is not created when I use launch file. If I do the same thing in the terminal the file is created and no errors >/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245536/rosbag-in-roslaunch,-save-rosbag-to-specific-directory/) by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2016-10-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use the [`args`](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) flag to pass in the arguments as you would from the command line:

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="record" args="-O <PATH_TO_BAGFILE>" name="record" output="screen"/>
```

---

**EDIT**

Even though this is probably not the way it is intended, you could also go with the prefix (note, lower case o):

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="record" args="-o <PATH_TO_BAGFILE>" name="record" output="screen"/>
```

e.g. `-o ~/Desktop/` would result in the file `/home/mig/Desktop/_2016-10-12-17-06-59.bag` on my system. But this is rather a workaround then a proper solution.

---

**EDIT2**

whoops, soory about that. Seems like the `~` shortcut for the users home directory cannot be resolved from the launch file. So you need to specify the full path, i.e. `/home/<USER>/...` for it to work.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) on 2016-10-12**:
hmm, cannot seem to get it to work, I try to access a folder on a SD-Card, where there is write access. So I did:  but cannot see any output.

**Comment by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) on 2016-10-12**:
@mig Do I need to specify the name of the file? I would rather have that it is generated based on a timestamp, is this possible?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-10-12**:
yes, you need to specify the filename with `-O`. For an alternative, see edit above.

**Comment by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) on 2016-10-13**:
Weird I cannot seem to get it to work: `[ccamera/record-2] process has died [pid 26717, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rosbag/record -o ~/Desktop/ __name:=record __log:=/root/.ros/log/6c14908a-9087-11e6-ad7f-00044b5ab358/ccamera-record-2.log].`
The logfile is not created either.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-10-13**:
whoops, soory about that. Seems like the `~` cannot be resolved here. So you need to specify the full path, i.e. `/home/<USER>/...` for it to work.